# how Data transfer can be done from service to activity?

Tags: android, service

I have multiple applications and a single service, i want to create a communication between the apps and the service. I am saving the value in the service which one of the application has sent. Now I am trying to read the same value by some another application from the service.

How this can be achieved? I don't want to call explicit intent from the service and neither implicit intents since implicit intents will give a selection option to choose the desired app, which i don't want. Please advice.

Comment: What's the value you're trying to share?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to do this job. You don't need a background service to do this. You can fire an intent and the same can be consumed by other applications which register for the specified intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

using BroadcastReceiver,

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            //              Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            //          String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
            //                  Toast.makeText(context,bundle.getString("eventName"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int icon = R.drawable.event;
            CharSequence notiText = "Event Notification";
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notiText,time);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Setting.class);
                     //put data in notificationIntent ....>>>>>



            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,intent.getStringExtra("eventName"),intent.getStringExtra("eventDescription"), contentIntent);
            int SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED =  1;
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            Toast.makeText(context,"aavechhe "+intent.getBooleanExtra("Flag",false),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(intent.getIntExtra("month",0)==cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"aavechhe "+cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);
            }
            if(intent.getBooleanExtra("Flag",false))
                notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **NOTE: This is example of notification, you have to make some changes in this code**